# The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

The following code tries to serialize an item and de-serialize using its interface:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Item item = new Item { A = 123321 };

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, item);
            ms.Position = 0;
            Serializer.Deserialize<IItem>(ms);
        }
    }
}


[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(Item))]
public interface IItem
{
    int A { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class Item : IItem
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

Throws the following exception when trying to deserialize the item:

```
The type cannot be changed once a serializer has been generated for Test.Item (Test.IItem)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean getBaseKey) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 388
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKeyImpl(Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\RuntimeTypeModel.cs:line 362
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.GetKey(Type& type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 982
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 576
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 506
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Meta\TypeModel.cs:line 488
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source) in C:\Dev\protobuf-net\protobuf-net\Serializer.cs:line 69
   at Test.Program.Main() in ...
```

Any thoughts/workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is a bug; short version... don't use interfaces as the **root** (outermost) type. Is logged and planned to fix; just... limited geek time. Interfaces work correctly as *members*; just... not as the *root* object.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Any chance you can post it as an answer so I can flag it as the correct one?